Записать в переменную значение из строки вывода python
Допустим у меня есть список
a = ['d', 3, 'w', 24]
Если я хочу вывести этот список на экран (в строку вывода), я пишу print(a) (логично)
Возможно ли мне записать в переменную _a тот текст, который выводится на экран, когда я пишу print(a)?

Просто сделайте преобразование в строку
a = ['d', 3, 'w', 24]
s = str(a)
print(a)
print(s)


import io

output = io.StringIO()       # создание «файла» в памяти
print(a, file=output)
a_ = output.getvalue()       # получение содержания файла после вызова print()
output.close()

(В переменной а_ будет строка "['d', 3, 'w', 24]\n")

Обьяснение:
В вызове функции print() я добавил параметр file=output, чтобы вывод был не на экран, а в файл. Затем в переменную а_ я присвоил содержание этого файла.
Но не нужно было применить реальный файл, а только симуляцию файла в памяти с использованием модуля io.

Примечание:
То самое с применением контекстного менеджера (спасибо CrazyElf за полезный комментарий):
import io

with io.StringIO() as output:
    print(a, file=output)
    a_ = output.getvalue()


@CrazyElf, вы совершенно правы, спасибо, я добавил это в мой ответ.

Я видел, плюс поставил )

@CrazyElf, спасибо еще раз.

a_ = str(a)           # в переменной а_ будет строка "['d', 3, 'w', 24]"


Этот подход к решению вашей проблемы возможно благодаря тому, что  вызов функции print(arg) на самом деле сначала применит на аргумент arg функцию str(), и только после этого выведет на экран результат этого применения с переходом на новую строку.

Это по сути то же, что в ответе MBo

@isolor, точно то же, но с объяснением, почему результат соответствует выводу на экран.

Такое имеет смысл добавлять комментарием (предложением дополнить вопрос), а не плодить одинаковые по сути ответы

@insolor, когда бы комментарий был коротким и все бы было ясно, я бы так сделал. Но по моему в комментарии бы это не выглядело так наглядно.

Немного передалал код от @MarianD, чтобы убрать лишнее
import io

a = ['d', 3, 'w', 24]

with io.StringIO() as buffer:
    print(*a, file=buffer)
    a_ = buffer.getvalue().strip()

print(a_)

Вывод
d 3 w 24

Здесь остаются только значения без "лишних" символов, что может не соответствовать пожеланиям, но как вариант оставлю
